# PDFBox 1.8.9 add external signature

Tags: .net, pdfbox

I want to add external signature to a PDF using PDFBox. I found some examples with PDFBox 2 in java, but I can't find any way to use PDFBox 2 in .net, so I want to know if I can do this with PDFBox 1.

Comment: there is an issue about .net with 1.8 in PDFBox, it doesn't work due to a problem with IKVM (which is no longer supported by its author). Also, PDFBox .net isn't supported. PDFBox is for java.

Comment: Since your username is iText you could try iText for C#.

Comment: I did it with iText, and now I  want to do it with PDFBox. PDFBox works in .net, I have tried, but I want to know if I can add external signature with 1.8., because I can't use 2.0 in .net

Comment: Here's the issue where we found out that FileOutputStream doesn't work properly with IKVM: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4312

Comment: So..I have no way to do this in .net..

Comment: I've tried in java..  My sign method is :  MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            
            byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(content.readAllBytes());
          
            String base64Hash = Base64.encodeBytes(hashBytes);
            
            String signature = (Base64 from server)
            return Base64.decode(signature);  And I get invalid signature..

Comment: See my answer to you on the user mailing list, assuming that it is you.